# How to link an entity from one table into another?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin

How can I link an entity that already exists in another table into my `important_table`? I could insert the ID but then that would require a query. What I want is that the system automatically maps the element in the `people_table` to the `important_table`.

```
@Entity(name = "important_table")
data class ImportantEntity(
        @Id @GeneratedValue @Column(name = "id")
        val id: Short = 0,

        @Embedded
        val person: Person
)
```

Person Entity

```
@Entity(name = "person_table")
data class PersonEntity(
        @Id @GeneratedValue @Column(name = "id")
        val id: Long = 0,
        ...
)
```

I tried embedded but that creates a duplicate Person in the db. I want the link so that I can find "important" people easy and still get the same data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `@OneToOne` mapping to let Hibernate (or any ORM) knows you are linking the tables together.

```
@Entity(name = "important_table")
data class ImportantEntity(
        @Id @GeneratedValue @Column(name = "id")
        val id: Short = 0,

        @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        val person: Person
)
```

When you say: `I could insert the ID but then that would require a query`, indeed, it does... But with the `FetchType.EAGER`, it's your ORM that will execute the extra query for you... It is transparent.

Nonetheless, be careful with that, if you don't pay attention to your relationships, you can end up loading the entire db in memory...

As explained [in this site](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Embedded.html), and [this tuto](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-embedded-embeddable), `@Embedded` is used to help having a nice and clean object definition, while **storing the data into one table** instead of 2... For instance, in your case, you would be storing the data from the class `Person` into the table `ImportantTable`.

Hope it helps !